# ConstraintLayout getting extended with the increasing tablerows in the TableLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

How to increase the length of the ConstraintLayout with the increasing tablerows in the TableLayout?

Comment: share your xml file

Comment: if you try then add your xml code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:text="Time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1" />

        <TextClock
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textClock"
            android:layout_column="2" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:text="First Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1" />

        <EditText
            android:width="200px"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:text="Last Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1" />

        <EditText
            android:width="100px"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <RatingBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
            android:layout_column="2" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_column="2" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```